# What's the right way to ask if something belongs to someone or something

Tags: word-choice, grammar, phrases

There are two devices, and I have an extra nail or spare part.  I want to ask which device the nail belongs to, in a simple way.  Should I say:

> 1. Who's this nail belongs to?
> 2. Who's this nail?
> 3. Which's this nail belongs to?

Comment: 'Who does this nail belong to?' may be contracted very informally to 'Who's this nail belong to?'

Comment: Who’s nail is this?  Is pretty idiomatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you start with this article regarding [who's versus whose](http://grammarist.com/usage/whos-whose/), the difference being that *whose* represents possession, where *who's* implies existence.  The apostrophe-s can mean either "is" or "has."  In some informal settings, it can also stand for "does," but more often people will not abbreviate "does"

Thus, if you are asking about a *person* that a spare part belongs to, you can try one of these:

> Whose part is this?
>
> Who does this part belong to?

However, a *device* is not a person.  To ask about a device try:

> Which device does this part go with?
>
> Which device's part is this?

Comment: Is this really of a suitable standard for ELU? Hence my comment rather than answer, and close-vote.

Answer (score 0):

If the nail belonged to a **person**, and you wanted to find out which person it belong to, you could say

"Whose is this nail?"

"Who does this nail belong to?"

"Who's this nail belong to?"  (this is a contraction of "Who does this nail belong to?")

However, in this case you want to know about a **device** that the nail "belongs to".  Strictly speaking a nail can't "belong to" a device as the device cannot "own" things, but it's common usage to talk about inanimate objects owning other objects: what we really mean is that the nail is in a list of objects which are associated with that device.

So, sticking with "belonging", you could say

"What device does this nail belong to?"

or

"What does this nail belong to?"

or, shortening it further,

"What's this nail belong to?"

If *I* had a nail, and i wanted to know which device it was associated with, i would probably say

"What does this nail **go with**?"

which means "What is this nail associated with", or a contracted version

"What's this nail go with?"

If it wasn't obvious (to the person that i was speaking to) that i was asking about the **device** that the nail goes with, i would say

"Which device does this nail go with?"

I don't think that this can really be shortened any more.  Some people might say

"What device does this nail go with?"

Strictly speaking this is grammatically incorrect (it should be "which", not "what") but, again, this might be acceptable as a colloquialism.

Comment: Is this really of a suitable standard for ELU?

Comment: @cobaltduck i stand corrected, thanks.  I'll amend my answer.